# Serving an Angular2 CLI built app using Nginx throws 404, 403

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-cli

I used Angular-CLI to create a test app and serve it using Nginx. Got either a 404 or a 403. I guess it is a problem with my Nginx config but just to be additionally sure, I have provided all the steps that I performed to get to this point.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Installed angular-cli: `npm install -g @angular/cli`
2. Started a new project: `ng new test-angular`
3. Checked using `ng-serve` and it works.
4. Built the project to be served using nginx: `ng build`. Creates a `dist` folder within the project directory.
5. Changed my nginx config:

   ```
   events { 
       worker_connections 1024;
   }

   http {
       include mime.types;
       default_type application/octet-stream;

       server {
           listen 80 default_server;
           root /home/mellkor/test-angular/dist;
           index index.html index.htm;
           server_name localhost;
           location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           }
       } 
    }
   ```

`nginx -s reload` successful. On hitting `localhost`, I get a 404 Not Found.

Based on some suggestions, changing to `try_files $uri /index.html` gives me a 403 Forbidden.

Another question: since `ng init` doesn't seem to work anymore, how can I initialize an existing angular2 application and build it to production using angular-cli?

Yes I did refer [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4269) closed topic, but there is no solution there so far.

**Additional Information:**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
node: 7.5.0
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.4.8
@angular/compiler: 2.4.8
@angular/core: 2.4.8
@angular/forms: 2.4.8
@angular/http: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.8
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.8
@angular/router: 3.4.8
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.8
```

Comment: Could you check whats the value of base href in dist/index.html, look for such a line `<base href="">`?

Comment: `<base href="/">` .. is that ok? @cpz

Comment: Yes that seems to be ok. Its difficult to zero down the issue with above information. Could you make sure nginx has right permissions on the folder http://askubuntu.com/questions/9402/what-file-permissions-should-i-set-on-web-root?

Comment: All my folder contents have `-rwxr-xr-x` .. ok maybe this is a stupid question.. Does running nginx as a superuser process cause any problems?

Comment: Running as super user shouldn't be a problem. I would suggest you try serve to some simple index.html only from the intended directory and see if that works.

Comment: Good idea.. Unfortunately cannot do that either.. hmm.. weird

Comment: It definitely is some config problem with nginx or permissions issue.

Comment: The default nginx conf pointed to a HTML file in my `/usr/share/nginx/html` .. and it had worked. So i copied the entire build to that folder and it worked as well. After I `chown`'d to root:root. I did the same in my home dir and it failed. FYI .. Thanks a lot btw @cpz

Comment: I am having the same issue and i will post an answer as soon as i got it.

Your issue is related with the fact that you are serving index.html and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be one of the possibility, that's why you are getting errors 404/403:

- Wrong base href in index.html head tag
- Wrong --base-href value while ng build command
- Wrong nginx configuration(i.e. server root OR server location /)
- Wrong rights to the files(i.e. /dist folder) that Nginx have to serve

Here is the solution:

Suppose you want to deploy your angular app at HOST: `http://example.com` and PORT: `8080`
Note - HOST and PORT might be different in your case.

Make sure you have `<base href="/">` in you index.html head tag.

Also, check that you have correct rights to /dist files which Nginx have to serve. Here is the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795350/nginx-403-forbidden-for-all-files).

1. Firstly, go to your angular repo (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld) path at your machine.
2. Then build /dist for your production server using the following command:

   ng build --prod --base-href http://example.com:8080
3. Now copy /dist (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld/dist) folder from your machine's angular repo to the remote machine where you want to host your production server.
4. Now login to your remote server and add following nginx server configuration.

   ```
   server {

       listen 8080;

       server_name http://example.com;

       root /path/to/your/dist/location;

       # eg. root /home/admin/helloWorld/dist

       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {

           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

           # This will allow you to refresh page in your angular app. Which will not give error 404.

       }

   }
   ```
5. Now restart nginx.
6. That's it !! Now you can access your angular app at http://example.com:8080

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @viks The problem was with the rights to the files that Nginx had to serve. I changed that and it worked fine. You could probably add that to the solution and I could accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Mellkor for sharing your findings. I have updated solution.